# Plus quam umquam sciebas oblitus sum

Tags: translation-check, english-to-latin-translation

Please check if my translation is correct for this phrase: **I have forgotten more than you ever knew:**

> Plus quam umquam sciebas oblitus sum

Is the word order correct, or should I put *oblitus sum* first? Should I have to use *tu* here or it can be omitted?

Comment: (Should it be *plura* as the object of *oblitus sum*?)

Comment: *Tu* is rarely obligatory, but I'd use it since there's some contrastive emphasis on "you" here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change three things.

First, instead of *plus*, which in context would mean "more often" or "to a greater extent" and usually signals that the verb is to be repeated, I would use the plural direct object *plura* (more things). Now the comparison makes sense.

Second, I would use a perfect tense rather than an imperfect with *umquam*. The perfect is much more common, since the word means "at any point."

Third, I would put the *quam* clause at the end rather than embedding it, since that's more natural.

> *Plura oblitus sum quam umquam scivisti.*